# External Screens (HDMI and Displayport) and External Keyboard (USB) don't work simultaniously after new Debian dual boot installation

Tags: debian, dual-boot, usb-device

I just installed Debian 11 on my Thinkpad as dual boot with windows.
In windows everything works fine.
In Debian when I first start the device the external monitors remain black but keyboard and mouse input from external usb devices work well. Laptop screen and laptop keyboard work in either case.
All devices are connected to a docking station, which is supplied with power.
After undocking the connection and redocking the laptop. The screens turn on, but the external usb inputdevices such as keyboard and mouse stop working. Laptop keyboard and trackpad remain fine.
The devices still get recognised with lsusb, but their input is not passed through.

I am grateful for all tips.

Comment: Have you looked for any special driver for your device specific hardware?

Answer (score 0):

Installed some of the non-free libraries and issue sorted it self out.

Comment: Could you expand a little on that? For example, which libraries?